# SELECT dentro do UPDATE

Tags: c#, sql

Tenho o seguinte Banco de Dados:

```
    cd_telefone|cd_cliente  |nr_ddd |nr_telefone
    1          | 30         | 11    |2562-2791
    2          | 30         | 11    |2562-2791
    3          | 31         | 13    |8888-8888
    4          | 30         | 11    |5555-5555
    5          | 30         | 13    |9623-54002
    6          | 30         | 11    |1111-2525
```

Minha intenção e passar o valor do ddd e telefone, e retornar o cd_telefone, e a partir do cd_telefone, atualizar o numero existente.

Meu Código esta assim, não da erro, porem não funciona:

```
UPDATE tb_telefones SET nr_ddd='" + dddNovo + "', nr_telefone='" + telNovo+ "'
WHERE cd_telefone = (
    SELECT cd_telefone FROM tb_telefones 
    WHERE nr_ddd='" + dddAntigo + "' AND nr_telefone='" + telAntigo + "'
)
```

Comment: Qual o banco de dados que você está usando? SQL Server / Oracle?

Comment: Na verdade é access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como explicação do comentário na minha resposta acima:

o select que você esta utilizando é :

```
    UPDATE tb_telefones SET nr_ddd='" + dddNovo + "', nr_telefone='" + telNovo+ "' 
    WHERE cd_telefone = (SELECT cd_telefone
                         FROM tb_telefones
                         WHERE nr_ddd='" + dddAntigo + "'
                           AND nr_telefone='" + telAntigo + "'
    )
```

tente utilizar desta forma :

```
    UPDATE tb_telefones SET nr_ddd='" + dddNovo + "', nr_telefone='" + telNovo+ "'
    WHERE cd_telefone =(SELECT top 1 cd_telefone
                        FROM tb_telefones
                        WHERE nr_ddd='" + dddAntigo + "'
                          AND nr_telefone='" + telAntigo + "'
    )
```

assim no select você pega apenas o primeiro valor retornado pelo select

Comment: Ta dando esse erro:
Erro de sintaxe na expressão de consulta 'cd_telefone =(SELECT top1 cd_telefone FROM tb_telefones WHERE nr_ddd='11' AND nr_telefone='11112525')'

Comment: desculpa o TOP 1 é separado

Comment: Corrigi, ele não da erro, porem mesmo assim não atualiza o banco de dados.

Comment: Os dois Códigos estavam certos, a inserção do atributo que estava incorreto. Obrigado pela força Todos

Answer (score 4):

Para que funcione você teria que se certificar que o resultado do seu select seja apenas de um valor, você pode fazer isso ultilizando por exemplo :

```
SELECT top1 cd_telefone FROM tb_telefones WHERE nr_ddd='" + dddAntigo + "' AND nr_telefone='" + telAntigo + "')
```

Comment: Desculpa não entendi, sou novo nessa área, o que eu devo substituir para retornar somente um valor?

Comment: existe um comando dentro do sql que se ultiliza no "SELECT" que é o "TOP 1" sendo que serve para retornar apenas o primeiro registro do seu select

Comment: Esse comando estou utilizando no C#, Introduzi o TOP 1, quando executo não da erro, porem não atualiza o banco tbm.

Comment: o seu update é o seguinte: UPDATE tb_telefones SET nr_ddd='" + dddNovo + "', nr_telefone='" + telNovo+ "'
WHERE cd_telefone = (
    SELECT cd_telefone FROM tb_telefones 
    WHERE nr_ddd='" + dddAntigo + "' AND nr_telefone='" + telAntigo + "'
)

Comment: Correto, meu UPDATE esta assim. Porem não atualiza no banco.

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente utilizo um loop nesta situação:

for dd in( (SELECT cd_telefone
          FROM tb_telefones
         WHERE nr_ddd = '" + dddAntigo + "'
           AND nr_telefone = '" + telAntigo + "')loop

UPDATE tb_telefones
   SET nr_ddd = '" + dddNovo + "', nr_telefone = '" + telNovo+ "'
 WHERE cd_telefone = dd.cd_telefone;

end loop;

Comment: Não manjo muito da sintaxe do sql, como que eu colocaria no meu código? o código completo, sem quebra de linha!

Answer (score 2):

Me desculpe eu não havia lido com a devida atenção a sua pergunta.

Acredito que no seu caso apenas trocar o **=** por **in**

UPDATE tb_telefones SET nr_ddd='" + dddNovo + "', nr_telefone='" + telNovo+ "'
WHERE cd_telefone **in** (
    SELECT cd_telefone FROM tb_telefones 
    WHERE nr_ddd='" + dddAntigo + "' AND nr_telefone='" + telAntigo + "'
)

Onde você vai incluir esse codigo.

Comment: Estou usando o código no c#. Coloquei o código que vc me passou, não da erro entretanto, tbm não atualiza o banco.